# Function parameters - how to use a pre-defined list instead of string value

Tags: c#, .net

This should be simple but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a function to send data to an API:

```
public bool UpdateCustomer(int customerid, string status) 
{
     apicall(customerid, status);
     return true;
}

UpdateCustomer(1234, "shipped")
```

This works fine. But the API has a predefined list of acceptable statuses, and I don't want to leave it to the person calling the function to get it right, I want to create some sort of enum or something:

```
public bool UpdateCustomer(int customerid, Status status) 
{
     apicall(customerid, status);
     return true;
}

UpdateCustomer(1234, Statuses.Shipped)
```

I want to pass the value to the API of their actual accepted value, "shipped".

I've tried creating a class with static strings:

```
public class Status
{
    public static string Cancelled = "cancelled";
    public static string Unsubmitted = "unsubmitted";
    public static string Saved = "saved";
    public static string Submitted = "submitted";
    public static string Arrived = "arrived";
    public static string Completed = "completed";
    public static string Shipped = "shipped";
}
```

but when I go to call UpdateCustomer(1234, Status.Shipped), it says it can't convert from a string to Status. I've done this with enums plenty of times but I can't use an enum because those only support int values.

What is the easiest way of doing this with string values (or anything besides integers, really)?

Edit: It does work if I set the function to public bool UpdateCustomer(int customerid, string status) and call it with UpdateCustomer(1234, Statuses.Shipped) but that defeats the purpose of idiot-proofing this, you can still pass whatever string value you want. I really want the function parameter to be type of Status so it forces the caller to use one of the pre-defined statuses.

Comment: Why not use an actual Enum? `Status.Shipped` is every bit as clear as "shipped" and perhaps more foolproof.  The fact that they are integral values under the hood is an implementation detail

Comment: I agree with Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp. If you need to pass the string value of the enum to UpdateCustomer, just use UpdateCustomer(1234,status.ToString())

Comment: Because then I still have to write code to go lookup that Status.Shipped string value somehow, I was hoping there was a way to do it all at once.

Comment: @dcp That only works if the enums are named exactly the same. Also what if it's some other object besides a string.

Comment: @Tim Andrews - So why not name the enum values exactly the same then? Isn't that the goal, to match the value you need to send to the UpdateCustomer API?

Comment: If you want to convert an enum to a string just create a lookup dict. `Dictionary<MyStatusEnum, string>`. Then just do `myDict.Add(MyStatusEnum.Status1, "Status 1");`

Comment: I asked this as a simple question but in practice I may need to get more complicated like returning a complex object or internal values that make no sense to the person calling the function. I guess I'll just have to write code to look up the underlying data based on the enum value.

Comment: @emsimpson92 Now we're getting somewhere! I think this is going in the direction I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a dictionary. Let's say you have a "Status" enum with 3 values. `Complete`, `Incomplete`, and `Abandoned`. Then you'll want to create a dictionary to be used as a lookup table.

```
Dictionary<Status, string> statusDict = new Dictionary<Status, string>()
{
  { Status.Complete, "Complete" },
  { Status.Incomplete, "Incomplete" },
  { Status.Abandoned, "Abandoned" }
};
```

When you receive the Status enum from them (CustomerStatus), all you need to do for your API call is...

`apicall(customerID, statusDict[CustomerStatus]);`

Comment: Thanks this is a simple but effective solution that can support more complex object types. Marked as answered!

Comment: But a caller can then use: `var invalidStatus = (Status)-1; UpdateCustomer(1, invalidStatus)` and this throws a KeyNotFound exception..

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Status
{
  Cancelled,
  Saved,
..
}


public bool UpdateCustomer(int customerid, Status status) 
{
     apicall(customerid, status.ToString());
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
enum StatusEnum
{
    Cancelled,
    Unsubmitted,
    Saved,
    Submitted,
    Arrived,
    Completed,
    Shipped
}

public bool UpdateCustomer(int customerid, StatusEnum status) 
{
     string statusStr;
     switch(status)
     {
        case StatusEnum.Cancelled:
          statusStr = "cancelled";
          break;
        case StatusEnum.Unsubmitted:
          statusStr = "unsubmitted";
          break;
        case StatusEnum.Saved:
          statusStr = "saved";
          break;
        case StatusEnum.Submitted:
          statusStr = "submitted";
          break;
        case StatusEnum.Arrived:
          statusStr = "arrived";
          break;
        case StatusEnum.Completed:
          statusStr = "completed";
          break;
        case StatusEnum.Shipped:
          statusStr = "shipped";
          break;
        case default:
          throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
     apicall(customerid, statusStr);
     return true;
}
```

Comment: This will more or less accomplish the same thing as a `Dictionary<StatusEnum, string>`

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 This is how I've done it before it just seems like there should be an easier way to return non-integer or string values from an enum. I think I'm going to try the Dictionary method.

Comment: sure ... even a .ToString().toLower() on the StatusEnum would do... but then you have Enum values on APIs that controll more than one param, or your initialization code for the Lookup/Dictionary that holds your api params based on the enum is in one place and the api wrapper in another ... when in doubt ... keep it simple and stupid

Comment: @TimAndrews if you just want a more elegant solution, you can put attributes on your enum members...